# The provided &quot;teamcity&quot; reporter does not exist. Check that you have specified the report format correctly

Tags: testing, automated-tests, teamcity, e2e-testing, testcafe

suddenly the test I have in testcafe stop working.

I have try to reinstall again the teamcity reporter with:

```
npm install -g testcafe testcafe-reporter-teamcity
```

and

```
npm install testcafe testcafe-reporter-teamcity
```

I can see that I have the folder testcafe-reporter-teamcity in my node_modules. But for some reason it cant find it.

Still the error that I get when running my test in local with the command:

```
testcafe firefox tests -c 4 --skip-js-errors --reporter teamcity
```

It will return the error:

```
ERROR The provided "teamcity" reporter does not exist. Check that you have specified the report format correctly.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue.

Just downgrading the version to 
`"testcafe-reporter-teamcity": "1.0.10"`
seems to work perfectly.. for some reason 1.0.11 is giving this issue.